# Use rails metaprogramming to construct dependency tree for view files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, metaprogramming

My team inherited a large rails monolith (~1000 paths when you run `rake routes`) and has been asked to convert to API backend (to be consumed by js-based SPA, also under development)

For planning purposes I'm looking for a way to build a list that will map every view template and/or partial to the routes and/or controller actions that depend on it.

For example:

```
/app/views/articles/index.html.erb - ArticlesController#index
/app/views/articles/show.html.erb - ArticlesController#show
/app/views/articles/_article.html.erb - ArticlesController#show, UsersController#recently_published, UsersController#recently_viewed
/app/views/articles/_some_obsolete_partial.html.erb - [No dependencies found]
# etc
```

Any ideas on an elegant way to compile this list of dependencies?

Comment: You might be able to rig something up using [coverband's](https://github.com/danmayer/coverband) view tracker. You need to ensure coverage yourself of course.

Comment: Thanks I will try!